# Pronunciation of the word "helmet"

Tags: pronunciation

Which pronunciation is correct? If both, which one is used more commonly?

/ˈhelmɪt/ or /ˈhelmət/

Comment: Not sure about other regions/dialects, but I'd be more likely to use /ˈhelmɪt/ myself. Though the actual sound I make is sort of in-between ɪ and ə if that makes sense, almost to the point where I'm just saying 'helmt'

Comment: My regions pronunciation would be el-met, h intentionally missing. The only way you can get a correct pronunciation is saying for which region you want the pronunciation for. For example, American English versus British English

Comment: I'd like to focus on the British pronunciation. Is it correct if I tell my students to pronounce "helmet" to simplify pronuciation (children aged 6-7) or will it be incorrect?

Comment: Again, for which pronunciation structure? RP? There's no objectively wrong way to say a word outside of a specific pronunciation structure.

Comment: British Received Pronunciation

Comment: /ˈhelmɪt/ is the way to go, then.

Comment: What about http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/helmet ?

Comment: But how about [www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/helmet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/helmet)?

Comment: The fact is that native English speakers pay very little attention to the vowels in unstressed syllables. Some people use /ə/ for all of them; some people use /ə/ for some and /ɪ/ for the rest, and some people use three or four different vowels. So it doesn't really matter exactly how you pronounce them.

Comment: So if I tell the students to pronounce this word as "helmet" will it be still correct? ( I mean simplified pronunciation).?

Comment: To my (SE UK) ear, the pronunciation with a schwa only identifies Germans such as [Helmut Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmut_Schmidt). All other usages have the short /ɪ/ sound for all speakers that I ever pay attention to. Use of the /e/ vowel here probably only occurs with nns in normal conversational contexts.

Comment: As another person from SE UK, I agree with FumbleFingers.

Comment: The version that Merriam-Webster's online pronouncer purports to be \ˈhel-mət\ is close to how I'd pronounce it (in the US Midwest), though the emphasis isn't quite right.  (Cambridge is the same, for both US and UK, and the emphasis is closer.)

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the first pronunciation is more common (that's that one I use, anyway).